# display mxml tag as text

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

i am new to flex,i want to disply mxml code as a text on mxml page(i dont want to evalute mxml tag it should be display as text only).something like shown in below link 
http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/inproduct/sdk/explorer/explorer.html

how can i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can always compile your project with the **view source** option enabled, and then your project code will be visible with out any additional fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TextArea control and set its text property. If this text is properly indented, if will be shown as the example you refer to.

Note that you cannot just read the MXML code at runtime since it is compiled down to ActionScript code. You'll need to copy the code into a string.